# Button - SetBackground() onClick disappearing

Tags: android, android-layout

In my app I'm simply trying to change a button's background drawable to another one with a very similar shape and a Yellow background (that that means the button has been pressed).
I don't think i can use a selector to do this since the button (actually i have multiple buttons) has to handle multiple clicks over time so the best option for me is to do that in code.

However when the button is clicked the background changes in Yellow as expected but it immediately returns White (default background drawable) even if i want it to keep that yellow background until i set it back to the default one.

What's the problem? Maybe the selector (I didn't set it)?

Java code

```
        myVisibility = false;
        myHighlighting = false;
        myContext = context;
        //noinspection Convert2Lambda
        myOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!myVisibility && !myHighlighting) {
                    discoverLetterButton();
                } else if (myVisibility && !myHighlighting) {
                    /*other code, not important
                    word += myCharacter;
                    WordTextView.setText(word);*/

                    /*here is the problem: the following line is executed but then the button immediately returns to the default drawable. */

                    v.setBackgroundDrawable(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.letter_button_front_highlighted, null));
                    //myButton.setClickable(false);
                }
            }
        };
        myButton.setOnClickListener(myOnClickListener);
        myButton.setClickable(true);
```

letter_button_front.xml (the default background)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
<corners
    android:radius="7dp"
    />
<solid
    android:color="#ffffff" //White
    />
<stroke
    android:width="3dp"
    android:color="#000000"
    />
</shape>
```

letter_button_front_highlighted.xml (the shape that i'm setting)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
<corners
    android:radius="7dp"
    />
<solid
    android:color="#ffffb32f" //Orange-yellow
    />
<stroke
    android:width="3dp"
    android:color="#000000"
    />
</shape>
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Since its changing then the onClickListener is being used and sets the new BG. Thus, the code you show is not the problem. Its either being reset elsewhere eg by another setBackgroundDrawable() call or the view is being recreated back to default elsewhere.

Comment: I know what you mean, however i've already checked the java class again and again but i still haven't found the cause of this colour change...that's why i thought the problem was the selector.

Comment: I finally got i working...the problem was the animation listener since its onend event was called endlessly (don't ask me why, that's probably a bug in android code).